# Upload muti photo use gem cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, cocoon-gem

i have a product.rb

```html
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments,dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :photos,inverse_of: :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos ,reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

product_controller.rb

```html
 def new 
        @product=Product.new
        @product.photos.new
 end
```

```html
def product_params 
        params.require(:product).permit(:name,:price,:decription,:category_id,photos_attributes: [:avatar])
    end
```

product/new.html.erb

```html
<%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.input :decription, as: :text%>
  <%= f.select :category_id , @categorys.collect{|c|[c.name,c.id]},include_blank:false %></br>
  <h2> photo</h2>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :photos do |photo|%>
    <%= render 'photo_fields', f:photo %>
    <%=link_to_add_association 'add photo', f, :photos%> 
 <%end%>
  <%=f.submit%>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

_photo_fields.html.erb

```html
<%= f.input :avatar , as: :file%> 
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove photo", f %>
```

and i uploaded muti photo for product . but when i show all photo of product , the product only saved a single photo
 **image**

```html
<strong>image</strong>
  <% @product.photos.each do |p| %>
  <%= image_tag p.avatar.url(:medium) %>
  <% end %>%>
```

I would like a product have many photo ( association 1 -n ). sorry i'm not good english. please help me !!

Comment: Can you show us what is posted to the controller? Small remarks: your strong-parameters should at least contain `[:id, :avatar, :_destroy]`, your `_photo_fields` partial should have a surrounding div with class `nested-fields` (for the remove to work).

Comment: I started this repo to reproduce your issue: https://github.com/wmavis/so_cocoon_multi_photo  Are you using a specific gem for file uploads?